# Is it inadvisable to store a hashed password in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, passwords

Is it inadvisable to store a hashed password in a user object in (server-side) session? It goes without saying that a salted and hashed password needs to be retrieved at some point to compare the hash to authenticate a given user, but once the comparison has taken place is there a quantifiable security risk associated with keeping it in the user object?

---

Given the discussion in the comments, the gist of the question was that password and hash data would be stored in the user object with the rest of the user data once retrieved from the database in a single, clean call. I understood before posting the question that of course there is *a risk*, but is it viable enough to warrant implementing a framework to clear it from the user, or would doing so just amount to good practice?

---

Given the responses, what I believe to be the best solution is to have a credentials object containing the password and salt that is associated with the user by ID but not stored directly in it.

When a user attempts to log in, the user object (which contains no password data) is retrieved from the database by email/username. The ID is then read and used to retrieve the associated credentials object. Password verification can then take place. If the password is correct, the user is put in session and the credentials object destroyed.

The result is a user object free of password data, so any potential associated security risks (however minimal they may be, as discussed in the question) are avoided. The other upshot is that there is no manual clearing of password data from the user object before its use. This is a more reliable system than requiring the data to be cleared each and every time, and if EF or a similar technology is being used there is no risk of accidentally erasing password data when the object's changes are pushed to the database.

Comment: If the session is compromised and the hash is used as a direct comparison in some "impersonation or elevation code" then one attack vector could inject a hash for another user, such as an administrator. While I won't say this is "insecure" (as it makes the assumption that the session is compromised which opens up a whole host of other problems), I would say it is "potentially less secure".

Comment: Normally you keep a variable indicating that the user has been authenticated instead.  This way there is no need to keep the password at all.

Comment: @pst The password? I would need to recover it, so it would be folded into the user object in a single EF call.

Comment: I would NEVER load the hash from the database into the server-side code... just calculate the hash (either in code or even better inside the DB) and do the comparison always on the DB-side... this way the only place any attack could ever retrieve a real hash would be the DB... not sure whether it is worth it but is narrows the attack surface to the DB.

Comment: The actual point of the question is not so much "should the password be kept in session", but rather "should a framework be put in place to ensure it is never kept in session".

Comment: @pst - The user object gets put in session. What is the risk of not removing the password from it before doing so. I understood before posting the question that it is of course better not to store it, but the question was more oriented towards whether or not there was a definitive, possibly obvious risk or if it was more of a question of good/bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I don't see any reason not to.  If the salted hash is secure, storing it in the server-side session shouldn't be any less secure than storing it in the database.

After all, the whole point of using a good salted hash is that even if your database is compromised and someone obtains all the salted hashes, they still wouldn't be able to recover the actual passwords.

Comment: And for good password hashing guideline go: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it would be overly unsafe, assuming you trust your server.

For an ideal password hash, a leak of the hash is nothing hugely critical. If the salt is not exposed, then it's effectively impossible to recover a password. If the salt and elements which construct the hash are exposed (other than the password), then it becomes possibly, but usually impractical because rainbow tables are useless and brute force is the only way. If you use a strong hashing algorithm such as SHA256 or Bcrypt you shouldn't have much to worry about..

Now that being said, I definitely don't recommend just giving strangers the password hash, but keeping it on your server should have little, if any, security implications

Answer (score 1):

If your session is not serialized for client-site storage, then there is no imidiate threat associated with this. But if you have to store hashes in sessions, then you should revise your authentication/authorization logic for better app design.

Comment: I doubt if he actually requires the hash to be stored in the session.  Most likely he is just storing a "User" object in the session, which just so happens to have the hash as one of its properties.

Comment: very true, and probably a good idea, but could cause problems if he later tries to do an update based on that object and inadvertently clears out the hash in the database.  It's still a good question though whether it's actually necessary to do that.

Comment: Yes, you guys understand the gist of the question ;).